# mvc razor dropdownlistfor display default from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

In my MVC view, I have a country list which is populated with all the countries.  This works ok and the user selects different countries & they are displayed ok.  I want the ability in Javascript to change that field back to "Select Country", how do I do this?

This is in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country, ViewBag.countrylist as SelectList, "Select Country", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "ddlcountry" })
</div>
```

This is my javascript

```
$("#ddlcountry").val(44);    //this works to set the country code to 44
$("#ddlcountry").val("Select Country");    //this does not work to display "Select Country" like the default when you first load the page
```

How can I have the default of "Select Country" show again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DropDownListFor()` method is generating the 'label option' with a `null` value

```
<option value="">Select Country</option>
```

to select that option with jQuery use

```
$("#ddlcountry").val('');
```